# How to change specific 'theme' colors in vim

Tags: vim

I would like vim to roughly match the color scheme of a python file in textmate. Here is a comparison of the two:

[image]

For example, I want a comment to be blue instead of red. If I have the hex codes for each of these colors, is there a place that I can change this in the `vimrc` or somewhere else? For example, how would I pass a hex code into the vim colorscheme:

```
" syntax highlighting
hi Comment    cterm=NONE ctermfg=#ddd        gui=NONE guifg=#ddd
hi Constant   cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkGreen   gui=NONE guifg=green3
```

Comment: *"how would I pass a hex code into the vim colorscheme"* -> you can only do so in guifg and not ctermfg. But you can enable `'termguicolors'` to have your terminal use GUI colors if that's available (it needs 24-bit color support for that.) Otherwise, you're limited to the 256 (or 16?) colors supported by your terminal...

Comment: If you're using a theme on textmate, find the name of that theme and look google for the same theme on Vim. I bet you'll find someone has already done the work of coming up with a similar or equivalent colorscheme that you can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you wanted in two different ways, the first one was much simpler, I just added

```
hi Comment guifg=#ddd
```

into my vimrc **just after the `colorscheme [colorscheme name]`**.

The second method is better for a big amount of changes and it's much harder. It bases around changing your colorscheme. You would do as follows:

1. Check what's your current colorscheme, by typing the command :colorscheme while in vim. if it's one of the defaults (blue.vim, darkblue.vim, default.vim, delek.vim, desert.vim, elflord.vim, evening.vim, industry.vim, koehler.vim, macvim.vim, morning.vim, murphy.vim, pablo.vim, peachpuff.vim, ron.vim, shine.vim, slate.vim, torte.vim, zellner.vim), then you need to go to $VIMRUNTIME/colors and edit which is yours. Otherwise check your ~/.vim directory for "colors" or search where you store plugins for the name of your theme. For example if you use vim-plug then plugins and themes are stored in ~/.vim/plugged. Copy the folder to not mess up the original theme and use a different name.

   2.After opening the folder of your theme open the only file in it - [theme].vim and search for the item you want to change, e.g. "Comment", change the hex value of the color, background etc.
2. Repeat to your liking to the time you'll get your theme looking how you want it to.
3. Set your colorscheme via `colorscheme [name-you-picked-earlier]`

The second option is also useful for creating full themes suited just to you.

Comment: See [How to customize colorschemes without editing their source files?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24846/18609) instead for a much better approach.

Answer (score -1):

There a very simple way to do the same.

Open vim and run the following.

```
:colorscheme<space><tab>
```

Once you press tab, you will see the list of available color schemes. Choose any of that. But the drawback is, you have to do that every time you open the vim. or simply save it to the .vimrc file.